# How do we style the DOM that is created by the material-ui in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How do we style the DOM that is created by the material-ui?

I am using GridListTileBar,  and their title property generate a DOM like this.

`<div class="MuiGridListTileBar-title-29" data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3/=1$3.0.1.$=11.0.0">test</div>`

The thing is, you cannot style with the class name above because it will change.  On top of that, I cannot add a new static class name in the code because it doesn't exist yet.

I guess I can traverse the DOM and then add a class name with jQuery, but I don't think this is the elegant solution.  Any idea?

Comment: https://material-ui-next.com/api/grid-list-tile-bar/ has a prop 'classes'. Check if that helps

Comment: So if you need to add styles to title you need to specify `<GridListTileBar classes={{title: "yourClassNameForTitle"}} />`

Comment: @oklas This worked pretty well, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Title have a `node` type, so you can pass any styled element like this:

```js
<GridListTileBar 
  title={
    <b
      style={{
        color:'red'
      }}
    >
      Test title
    </b>
  }
/>
```

Comment: The `b` tag is any tag taken just for example - you can use any html tag or react component.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for `GridListTileBar`, any props you provide to the component are passed to the root `div`.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/GridList/GridListTileBar.js

You should be able to pass `className` and see that it's applied

```
<GridListTileBar className='my-class' />
```